# How to calculate pandas DF values based on grouped column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm relatively new to Pandas dataframes and I have to do simple calculation, but so far I haven't found a good way to go about it.
Basically what I have is:

```
       type   group     amount
1       A     real        55
2       A     fake        12
3       B     real       610
4       B     fake        23
5       B     real        45
```

Now, I have to add a new column that would show the percentage of fakes in type total. So the simple formula for this table would be for A `12 / (55 + 12) * 100` and for B `23 / (610 + 23 + 45) * 100` and the table should look something like this:

```
       type   group     amount    percentage
1       A     real        55          
2       A     fake        12         17.91
3       B     real       610
4       B     fake        23
5       B     real        45          3.39
```

I know about `groupby` statements and basically all the components I need for this (I guess...), but can't figure out how to combine to get this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
percentage = {}
for type in df.type.unique():
    numerator = df[(df.type == type) & (df.group == 'fake')].amount.sum()
    denominator = df[(df.type == type)].amount.sum()
    percentage[type] = numerator / denominator * 100

df['percentage'] = list(df.type.map(percentage))
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me lots of new tools to work with!

Answer (score 1):

```
df['percentage'] = df.amount \
                 / df.groupby(['type']) \
                     .amount.transform('sum').loc[df.group.eq('fake')]).fillna('')
df
```

[image]

---

If handling multiple `fake` in `group` per `type`.  We can be a bit more careful.  I'll set the index to preserve the `type` and `group` columns while I transform.

```
c = ['type', 'group']
d1 = df.set_index(c, append=True)
d1.amount /= d1.groupby(level=['type']).amount.transform('sum')

d1.reset_index(c)
```

[image]

---

From here, you can choose to leave that alone or consolidate the `group` column.

```
d1.groupby(level=c).sum().reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: This answer assumes that there is only one fake group per type

Comment: @TedPetrou yes it does

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to make sure you accounted for multiple fake groups per type you can do the following

```
type_group_total = df.groupby(['type', 'group']).transform('sum')
type_total = df.groupby('type')[['amount']].transform('sum')
df['percentage'] = type_group_total / type_total
```

Output

```
  type group  amount  percentage
0    A  real      55    0.820896
1    A  fake      12    0.179104
2    B  real     610    0.899705
3    B  fake      23    0.100295
4    B  fake      45    0.100295
```